# If my creature has shadow and flying, can it only be blocked by creatures with shadow AND flying?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My understanding is that creatures with shadow can only block or be blocked by creatures with shadow, and creatures with flying can only be blocked by creatures with flying. If I have a creature with shadow and cast a spell that gives it flying (say, [Jump](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=193743)), can it now only be blocked by nothing but a creature that also has both those abilities?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a general sense, you are correct. Both abilities impose a restriction that's tracked individually. A creature must satisfy all the restrictions in order to block your super-evasive attacker.

My one niggle is that there are non-flyers that can block fliers, such as creatures with reach. And there are a few creatures, like [Wall of Diffusion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=4855), that don't have shadow but have "~ can block creatures with shadow as though ~ had shadow" as an ability, which allows them to block shadow creatures (and non-shadow creatures as well, since they don't actually have shadow).

Here's some comp rules for ya, with this exact example:

> **509.1b** The defending player checks each creature he or she controls to see whether it’s affected by    any restrictions (effects that say a
> creature can’t block, or that it can’t block unless some    condition
> is met). If any restrictions are being disobeyed, the declaration of
> blockers is illegal.
>
> A restriction may be created by an evasion ability (a static ability an attacking creature has    that restricts what can block
> it). If an attacking creature gains or loses an evasion ability after
> a    legal block has been declared, it doesn’t affect that block.
> Different evasion abilities are    cumulative.
>
> ***Example**: An attacking creature with flying and shadow can’t be blocked by a creature with flying but without shadow.*

Trivia: [Stronghold Overseer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=109671) has both flying and shadow natively. On a 5/5 body to boot!

Comment: Adding Intimidate to the mix would be another way of making a Flying/Shadow creature that another Flying/Shadow creature would not necessarily be able to block...

Comment: Check out the Oracle text of Wall of Diffusion. It's more clear as it says *may block as though it had shadow* as in *fulfills the shadow requirement*. Compared to the old *can block creatures with shadow* which sounds as something absolute.

Comment: @thesunneversets Now all it needs is horsemanship. ;)

Comment: Oh yeah, Horsemanship!  Fair in Portal: Three Kingdoms;  undercosted total unblockability in Eternal formats...

Comment: Why not throw fear in the mix as well? Or we could just give the guy some kind of landwalk or protection from creatures and be done with it. :)

Comment: @AndSoYouCode I'm a fan of WotC's recent decision to cut out the middleman entirely and just write "unblockable" on a couple of cards. In small doses, it lets new players focus on thinking about how to get the most out of their free attacks rather than how to set up the right conditions for their evasion abilities. (In larger doses it'd be as poor of a choice as the "trample is too hard so let's have 'assign damage as if it weren't blocked' instead" era.)

Comment: Yeah I agree! I must admit that I still really miss combat damage using the stack. Maybe it wasn't logical and a bit complicated, but it made soooo many cool moves available. Instant sacrifice abilities were such a blast...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need both to fulfill both requirements to be able to block a creature with both shadow and flying. You can fulfill these requirements either by having shadow and flying or through other abilities such as reach.